# Как осуществить возврат в начало меню switch?

Tags: c, switch

Как вернуться в начало, то есть запустить switch case снова, если ввели неверное значение ? В СИ нету bool, поэтому я вообще не понимаю как это правильно сделать, есть что-то типо такого, но всё же, в начало оно не возвращает.. И без использования goto.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter an integer of 10, 20, 30, 40, or 50\r\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        switch (n)
        {
        case 10:
            printf("You entered number 10.\r\n");
            break;
        case 20:
            printf("You entered number 20.\r\n");
            break;
        case 30:
            printf("You entered number 30.\r\n");
            break;
        case 40:
            printf("You entered number 40.\r\n");
            break;
        default: printf("Wrong number");
            return 0;


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уберите `return 0;` - это же завершение программы... Другое дело, что если после правильного ввода вы хотите завершить программу - замените на этот `return` все `break` :)

Comment: Уберите  `return 0;` или добавьте `continue;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `bool` есть в `<stdbool.h>`.
2. Уберите `return 0;` и тело цикла выполнится снова

Comment: Точнее как _Bool ;-). Да и не особо он нужен в этой задаче

Comment: Оу, и правда, что-то затупил. Спасибо :D

Comment: @Node_pro, `_Bool` в `<stdbool.h>` не определяется. Определяются там только `bool`, `false` и `true`.

Comment: помню в детстве спокойно обходился без bool ) есть же int

Comment: Уж если переделываете комментарий в ответ, то переделывайте до конца - ТС же спросил *запустить switch case снова,* ((если ввели неверное значение** - а в вашем решении это будет *всегда*, а не только при неверном решении... Я же не зря написал 2 части решения.

Comment: @Harry я не переделывал ваш комментарий в ответ. Думаю, ТС бы не принимал ответ, если бы поведение его не устраивало

Comment: typedef enum { false, true } bool; Вот тебе и бул